# Using a Larger MFD Capacitor with a UV Lamp Ballast

Tags: capacitor, repair, lamp, uv, ballast

I am attempting to repair a UV lamp for curing resins and epoxies. I determined the capacitor was the problem and ordered a replacement (7C100M33R). I got the last one the site had available - and they sent me the wrong one. They sent me a 12 MFD capacitor instead of a 10 MFD.

The UV lamp has a switch, potted ballast and this capacitor, that's all of the internals. Its output goes to a 100W Sylvania mercury arc bulb.

**Model of UV Lamp**: Spectroline Model SB-100P (120V, 60Hz, 1.05A)

**Original capacitor**: 10 MFD 330 VAC 50/60 Hz (Model 7C100M33R)

**Replacement capacitor**: 12 MFD 330 VAC 50/60 Hz (Model 7C120M33R)

Everything I have read discusses using a larger capacitor for a motor being okay, but because this is expensive equipment, I wanted to double check that a 12 MFD capacitor wouldn't damage the ballast. I need this repaired so I'd rather not send it back and wait for a replacement, if one even exists. I'm hoping this one will work. Please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a difference of 20% which is rather large in this application. You could damage the ballast (by overheating) or shorten the life of the lamp.

I suggest not doing it.

Comment: P.S. if the price you paid was anything like what a brief googling yielded ($100-ish), I would be tempted to return it and sub a 10uF motor run capacitor for maybe $5-6 from a local HVAC or appliance parts shop.

Comment: This may be discontinued by the mfr: https://www.radwell.com/en-US/Buy/PHILIPS/ADVANCE%20BALLAST/7C100M33R -- If you are using this on 50 Hz, the 20% lower frequency may compensate for the 20% higher capacitance, especially if it actually measures on the low side of the tolerance. So in that case it would present a lower risk.

Comment: Yes, Radwell is who I sourced it from. The UV lamp is old but we don’t have the funds for a new one (thousands of dollars). So I’ll take a $100 part that I know is valid for the machine than something else. But if I absolutely can’t find one with the right specs, I’ll try a run motor cap.